# Update sql table daily with values from another table

Tags: sql, .net

I need some help with updating a few of my sql tables that need to pull values from one main table each day.

My main table consists of status', descriptions and dates for updates that are made to it daily. I have 3 other tables that need to pull values from that main table based on their Status ID number. For example, if it is a **Type1** then it gets the the number of Reds, Greens, Yellows and the current date for that Type and it needs to do this daily.

After doing some research I saw that I need to implement something like this:

```
Update [TableA]
SET Date (select Date from [TableB] where [TableB].Date = [TableA].DateDiscovered and [TableB].Date IS NOT NULL) --not sure if this is write, this is just what I found online
```

Here are some examples of my two tables that would be used:

**Main Table**

[image]

**Secondary Table**

[image]

*So basically I need help with the following: the secondary table would need to count the greens, reds, oranges and yellows from the 'Status' column and put them in the designated columns. So if there were 4 greens, 2 reds, 1 yellow and 2 oranges they would be put in the corresponding columns in the secondary table. And I need this done each day and when it is done it would record the current date in the date column in the secondary table.*

Comment: Your sample query is not valid SQL.  Could you show some sample data that shows the secondary table before and after the update?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the use of a trigger? Also, an update statement can modify multiple fields at one time.

Comment: This is done differently in differnt database engines. Which database are you using? Also, show the structure of the tables involved.

Comment: @DanielB, I am using SQL Server 2012, I also made updates to my post that explains better with examples of my two tables.

Comment: Are you just trying to update TableA with some results from TableB?

Comment: @samyi, yes. So daily I would update the date to the current and the the sum of each of the colors into each column.

Comment: Use a view, no need for the second table as far as I can see. Then you can always be sure the counts are up to date. Unless you have a specific reason for storing the aggregate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to `INSERT` a new row to `Secondary Table` each day with a summary of all `Status` values in `Main Table`? Regarless of `Discovered` or `Escalated` in `Main Table`?

If so, you need to :

```
INSERT INTO SecondaryTable 
SELECT CAST(GetDate() as Date),
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Red,
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Orange,
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yellow,
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Green
FROM MainTable
```

Comment: this was perfect! Worked great but how do I get it to run once a day?

Comment: Add an SQL Server Agent job, with a T-SQL job step containing the SQL text above, and schedule the job to run as required.